# Difficulty with Facebook Comments Moderation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I am trying to implement moderation on Facebook comments plugin, which will be used in my site. I have made sure the following two tags are inside the HTML head section :

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="582222130,804179xxx"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="280627238712xxx"/>
```

I have placed the script just above the end of body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=280627238712xxx";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I have got the div tag in the right place:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.sss.net/xxx" data-num-posts="5" data-width="585">
```

The Facebook comment loads on the browser everything seems to work apart from the moderation when I visit [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=recent_comments) there are no comments at all. I have made sure that I have added myself as an admin, there are no space in-between the ids in tags in head tag (fb:admins).

Do I need to configure any setting when creating a Facebook app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it fixed at last !!

I forgot to put the

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

html tag, which created all these problems. Thanks a lot to everyone who made an effort to help ! Stackoverflow rocks !

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the appId that was used to get the plugin code looks different than the appID you have added in the meta tags. In your comment moderation tool, are you looking at the proper app ? Maybe check and see if changing the meta tag to the same app_id fixes it.

Comment: Thanks deesarus, I am still unable to moderate the content

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried splitting the fb:admins tag? (described here: [multiple fb:admins in og tags](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12422193/multiple-fbadmins-in-og-tags))

Second guess: Have you tried to debug the data-href-url with facebook debugger? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug all og-tags are cached for 24h hours - if you debug the url with the mentioned tool, then all cached data gets reloaded.

Comment: I had similar problem, I clicked "Scrap Again" in debug tool and my plugin finally worked. Thanks!